# Using where condition in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql query like this

```
Select col1, (select abc from table2 where def=1) as col2
From Table1 inner join table3 on Table1.id = table3.id
Where col2 = 4
```

The problem is that the where condition doesn't work. I get an error saying

> Invalid column name 'col2'

Kindly help me fix this sql query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that your actual query? Seems odd. The sub query isn't correlated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it in a `CROSS APPLY` and then reference in the `SELECT` and `WHERE`

```
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM   Table1
       INNER JOIN table3
         ON Table1.id = table3.id
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT abc
                    FROM   table2
                    WHERE  def = 1) C(col2)
WHERE  col2 = 4
```

Comment: @ypercube - Yes. I was thinking that there would be a difference if the sub query could return 0 rows rather than 1 (and that maybe I should use `OUTER APPLY` instead) but the `WHERE` clause takes care of that.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks. Can I use multiple queries in CROSS APPLY? What if I need a col3 similar to col2.

Comment: @Derin - The `SELECT` in the `CROSS APPLY` can return multiple columns and you can have multiple levels of `CROSS APPLY`. If you were to show your actual query there may well be simpler or more efficient ways though.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
WITH SubQuery AS (Col2) {
    SELECT 
        ABC
    FROM
        table2
    WHERE
        def = 1
}
SELECT
    T.Col1,
    S.Col2
FROM
    SubQuery S,
    Table1 T
    INNER JOIN table3 t3
        ON T.id = t3.id
WHERE
    S.Col2 = 4
```

Although I must say I agree with the first comment - this makes no sense since your subquery is not correlated (joined) to the rest of your query...