# Is there a way to set variables in a Select statement that can be used in the same statements WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to set a variable in a Select statement so it can be later used in the `where` clause.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT DateDiff(d,Time_Stamp,GetDate()) as Var1 FROM Report Where Var1 = 5
```

I noticed that the `ORDER BY Var1` clause, works fine, but when I try to use it in a where statement it doesn't work fine, it gives an error on the `Var1` column.

This doesn't work either because it doesn't return any rows.

```
DECLARE @Var1 int
SELECT @Var1 = DateDiff(d,Time_Stamp,GetDate()) FROM Report Where @Var1 = 5
```

If this does make sense to you, can you tell me what you would do in this case so you don't have to write redundant code like this...

```
SELECT DateDiff(d,Time_Stamp,GetDate()) FROM Report 
 Where DateDiff(d,Time_Stamp,GetDate()) = 5
```

?

Comment: Try to use Having Var1 = 5

Comment: @ManishJangir that gives an error.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Why `SELECT` a data which you want to filter on, knowing its value ? What's the point ? If you know that `DateDiff(d,Time_Stamp,GetDate())` has to be equal to 5, why not `SELECT 5 ... where DateDiff(d,Time_Stamp,GetDate()) = 5` ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you interrested to know how to do that with a table variable + merge statement?

Comment: @X.L.Ant This is an example, the reason is because `so you don't have to write redundant code` as stated in the question.

Comment: No, does not make sense to me. Write redundant code, live with it.

Comment: @Serge If its more complicated than the 3rd statement in my question, then probably not.

Comment: table variable + merge statement pretty much cover any need of this kind. But since it's tricky, I won't bother exaplining it if you're actually looking for a beginer-level work arround.

Comment: @Serge Yes, beginner level please, even though, I'm sure if you answered it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using where condition in sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115573/using-where-condition-in-sql-query)

Comment: @Serge - I don't see how "table variable + merge statement pretty much cover any need of this kind". Neither of them are remotely related to the ability to reference a column alias in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Martin, I didn't notice it was the same statement.

Comment: @Serge - Ah that explains it!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT r.*, DateDiff(d,Time_Stamp,GetDate()) diff
      FROM Report r
)
SELECT * FROM qry 
 WHERE diff > 1
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3059/2)**

Comment: I guess you have a valid answer, even though I know how to use that technique, but I was hoping for something more in the realm of not having to write a nested table inside a table or whatever you call it.

Comment: @ZeeTee IMHO you can only either use outer select or common table expression (`WITH`) if you deal with complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view of your table, and after, sort your view by Var1.
But you can't use your new Column Var1 in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Who has time for all that? Not me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Ext.var1
FROM Report AS R
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DateDiff(d,R.Time_Stamp,GetDate()), R.indexedColumn
) AS Ext(var1, var2)
Where Ext.var1 = 5
and Ext.var2 = 5
```

Be carefull with this, the where statement won't make SQL Server use any available Index on indexedColumn.